# Pentaho Spoon Simultaneous execution of same Job

Tags: pentaho, etl, pentaho-spoon

We have created a single Job in pentaho. We want to run this same job from .kjb file multiple times passing different parameters from command line. But as the code is a single source file, we are not able to execute in parallel. What is the solution for running single pentaho job in parallel?

Comment: Do you know the parameter values for all jobs when starting the first job, or will they come in randomly over time?

Comment: They are coming from a batch script. Just have to pass them to the Job

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use a wrapper Pentaho job that calls the same .kjb multiple times with different parameters. In this scenario you'd use the "Run Next Entries in Parallel" setting as it's described here: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Launching+job+entries+in+parallel

2) If you're using kitchen to run .kjb from the command line, you can take care about parallel execution in the shell script itself.